# Run-Time check failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted. ERROR? How to correct?

Tags: c

Below program gives desired output(Counts Words of 3 consecutive lines)
but it gives "Run-Time check failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'str' was corrupted"
and hangs. I tried but I could not find the solution. Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int i,count=0;

int main(void){

char str[3][1000];
char *ptr;

//Get user input
puts("Enter three lines:");
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    gets(&str[i][1000]);
}

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    ptr=strtok(&str[i][1000]," ");
    count++;

    while (ptr!=NULL)
    {
        ptr=strtok(NULL, " ");

        if (ptr!=NULL)
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
}

printf("%d words", count);
getch();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `gets(&str[i][1000]);` should be

```
 gets(str[i]);
```

But since `gets()` is deprecated you should really use

```
fgets (str[i], 1000, stdin);
```

A similar error appears on this line `ptr=strtok(&str[i][1000]," ");`

Comment: + better to suggest `fgets`

Comment: reply to "this": I changed as you said but it gave Error: argument of type "char" is not compatible with parameter of type "char *"

Comment: and indexing  `str[i][1000]` causes undefined behavior

Comment: `gets()` isn't deprecated - C11 removed it entirely, it's no longer C.

Answer (score 2):

You are corrupting the stack by passing &str[2][1000](3rd iteration of loop) to gets/strtok, which actually points to str[3] which is out of array bounds. You should simply pass str[i] or &str[i][0] to gets/strtok.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
gets(&str[i][1000]);
```

is very wrong, it gives `gets()` a pointer to the last character of each line, where (for the last line) there is no more space.

It should be:

```
if(fgets(str[i], sizeof str[i], stdin) == NULL)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "**Failed to read line %d\n", i);
  exit(1);
}
```

Note that [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) is much safer, you should avoid using `gets()`. You should also *check the return value* to make sure it succeeded.

Comment: According to fgets documentation your error handling is incorrect if the first read character is EOF, then fgets() doesn't read anything str remains unchanged but fgets return NULL. You code would indicate an error but it was an EOF. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/